# MediaSession Stop button vs. Pause button displayed

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-auto

How can I control when a Stop button vs. Pause button is displayed in the "Media control card" while playing audio in an Android Auto Media app?

I'm setting the actions in a `PlaybackState` object, then setting that in my `MediaSession` object like so (this is a very abridged example):

```
PlaybackState.Builder playbackState = new PlaybackState.Builder();
playbackState.setActions(PlaybackState.ACTION_PAUSE).build();
mMediaSession.setPlaybackState(playbackState);
```

I realize the actions value is a bit mask for a various combinations of actions, but no matter what I put in `setActions` I get a stop button.

**UPDATE:** It appears to be a bug with Google's Media Browser Service Simulator.  A workaround is to clear the app's data by selecting *Settings -> Apps -> Media Browser Service Simulator -> Clear Data* before running your app again.  I am using version 6.5.81 (1593596-030) of the simulator.  I also am experiencing this bug running the simulator on a physical Nexus 7.

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Run Google's sample app, Universal Music Player, hit PLAY, and a PAUSE button
   appears, as is expected because `actions |= PlaybackState.ACTION_PAUSE`
   is set in `MusicService.getAvailableActions()`.
2. Change the line to `actions |= PlaybackState.ACTION_STOP`,
   run the app, hit PLAY, and a STOP button appears, as is expected.
3. Change the value back to `actions |= PlaybackState.ACTION_PAUSE`, run the
   app, hit PLAY, and a STOP button appears, an unexpected behavior.
4. You can confirm through debugging that `actions` contains the bit
   mask value for PAUSE and not STOP.

Note: Although the square STOP button is displayed, the button's behavior is PAUSE.

**Workaround:**

1. Clear the app data: *Settings -> Apps -> Media Browser Service
   Simulator -> Clear Data*
2. Run the Universal Music Player app again in the simulator, hit PLAY,
   and the PAUSE button appears, as expected.

**UPDATE #2:** It seems that once the STOP button has appeared, the PAUSE button can never appear again, and this workaround is not useful.

Comment: Setting the action to `PlaybackState.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE` seemed like it would be a step in the right direction, but still didn't display a pause button.

Comment: Can you please specify whether you're seeing the stop button on the auto simulator or in an app? Also can you post your code which shows the mediaSession setup as well your code in MediaSessionCallback.onPlay(..)

Comment: @NageshSusarla, it appears to be a bug with the simulator, both when running in an emulator or on a physical device.  Please see my update above.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at the simulator code and keep you posted.

Comment: @NageshSusarla were you able to confirm that this is a bug?  Should I file a bug report?

Comment: Yes there is indeed some oddity but restarting the simulator seems to fix it for me. You can definitely file a bug for this! Thanks